# Auth with web parameter and without parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

In Laravel, When i'm using `auth('web')->user()` it's return the data. but when i using `auth()->user()` no data return.

why `auth()->user()` return no data?

i know about `web` and `api` middleware. by default laravel use `web`. but why i need to pass `web` parameter into `auth` function